# Extra commas in 'Share a link to this question via email,,, or

Tags: bug, status-declined

I looked at a couple of questions this morning and noticed we have a few extra commas in the text below the question:

[image]

Comment: Are you (like me) using an adblocker that also blocks things that look like social share buttons?

Comment: Cross-site duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/214355

Comment: @amon - Doh!  Yep,using ad blocker.  Thanks.

Comment: We won't be fixing this, as it is caused by ad blocker plugins.